# Notation for higher order partial derivatives in Leibniz

Tags: derivatives, notation, partial-derivative

Which one of the following two are correct?

$$ f_{xy} = \frac {\partial} {\partial y} (\frac {\partial f} {\partial x}) = \frac {\partial ^2 f} {\partial xy}$$

or

$$ f_{xy} = \frac {\partial} {\partial y} (\frac {\partial f} {\partial x}) = \frac {\partial ^2 f} {\partial yx}$$

Notice the order of $xy$ in the last term of both equations are switched
I am confused because of the following notation, which seems to contradict my belief

$$ f_{xy} = \frac {\partial} {\partial y} (\frac {\partial f} {\partial x}) = \frac {\partial ^2 f} {\partial y \partial x} $$
is this the same as this
$$\frac {\partial ^2 f} {\partial y \partial x} = \frac {\partial ^2 f} {\partial xy}$$
or is it the other way around
$$\frac {\partial ^2 f} {\partial y \partial x} = \frac {\partial ^2 f} {\partial yx}$$

Is the above different simply because there are 2 partials $\partial$ on the bottom instead of 1? So like the ordering also gets inverted or something?

---

Also how come the bottom partial doesn't gain more exponents but the top partial does w/ higher order derivatives?

e.g.

$$f_{xxx} = \frac {\partial ^3 f} {\partial x^3}$$ vs $$f_{xxx} = \frac {\partial ^3 f} {\partial ^3 x^3}$$

Comment: The second one is correct...............

Comment: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/HighOrderPartialDerivs.aspx

Comment: I'v never seen $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial xy}$. There is a $\partial$ symbol missing in the denominator in many cases .

Comment: @REr

the following seems to tell otherwise
http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~cds/articles/derivative.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On ${\mathbb R}^2$ with the standard coordinate functions $x$ and $y$ we have the partial differentiation operators $${\partial\over\partial x},\quad {\partial\over\partial y}\ .\tag{1}$$ Higher powers of these operators are written
$${\partial ^p\over\partial {\mathstrut x}^p},\quad {\partial ^q\over\partial {\mathstrut y}^q}\ .\tag{2}$$
For smooth functions the two operators $(1)$ commute, and it is then customary to write the product of the two powers $(2)$ as
$${\partial^{p+q}\over \partial {\mathstrut x}^p\partial {\mathstrut y}^q}\ .$$
If one has three variables $x$, $y$, $z$ one writes
$${\partial^3 f\over \partial x\partial y\partial z}=f_{xyz}\ ,$$
and similalry one has $$f_{xyzz}={\partial^4 f\over\partial x\partial y\partial{\mathstrut z}^2}$$
I have never seen the notation ${\displaystyle{\partial^2\over\partial xy}}$ for the mixed derivative ${\displaystyle{\partial^2\over\partial x\partial y}}$ before.

Comment: what would happen for 3 variables then in Leibniz notation? $$f_{xyz} = ???$$ Thanks for the response by the way, I appreciate this as a rookie entering the world of mathematics

Comment: just for the record, would the following hold?

$$
f_{xyzz} = \frac {\partial ^4 f} {\partial x \partial y \partial z^2}
$$